# How to make sure pairs of arrays are unique in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array as such:

```
$fake_categories = [
    [
        'handle' => 'food',
        'nice_name' => 'Food'
    ],
    [
        'handle' => 'travel',
        'nice_name' => 'Travel'
    ],
    [
        'handle' => 'fashion',
        'nice_name' => 'Fashion'
    ],
    [
        'handle' => 'food',
        'nice_name' => 'Food'
    ]
];
```

And I wish to make sure that the packages are unique (by the key `handle`). As you can see, the last item in the array is a duplicate and needs to be removed.

How can I perform a deep `array_unique`?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: @NigelRen Been wrangling with the thing for a good while now but can't find anything that's not fuckery inside for loops.

Comment: You could use: `$unique = array_unique($fake_categories, SORT_REGULAR);` that should give you the desired result.

Comment: @lovelace The documentation, at least for me, doesn't hint at the possibility of `SORT_REGULAR` solving my problem. How does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare the **entire sub-array** use @lovelace comment with [array-unique](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) with the `SORT_REGULAR` flag as:

```
$unique = array_unique($fake_categories, SORT_REGULAR);
```

If you just want the **'handle'** to be unique use [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to put it as key (which promise `handle` to be unique) as then [`array_values`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to remove the keys as:

```
$unique = array_values(array_column($fake_categories, null, 'handle'));
```

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/G83mL)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, @lovelace reply is correct. You can use it for your array

```
<pre>
$fake_categories = [
    [
        'handle' => 'food',
        'nice_name' => 'Food'
    ],
    [
        'handle' => 'travel',
        'nice_name' => 'Travel'
    ],
    [
        'handle' => 'fashion',
        'nice_name' => 'Fashion'
    ],
    [
        'handle' => 'food',
        'nice_name' => 'Food'
    ]
];

    $unique = array_unique( $fake_categories, SORT_REGULAR );
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($unique);
    echo '</pre>';
</pre>

which will generate output like this:
<pre>
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [handle] => food
            [nice_name] => Food
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [handle] => travel
            [nice_name] => Travel
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [handle] => fashion
            [nice_name] => Fashion
        )

)
</pre>
```